# How to make 15px of free space under the picture?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Krzysiek_35/Ljybwz97/44/

```css
body
{
    left: 8%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #6699cc;
}

.box3
{
    background-color: #191919;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px 40px 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #DDDDDD;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 400px;
}

.box3 > li
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.box3 > li span
{
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="box3">
  
        <li>
            <img src="pictures/contact/skype.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
            <span>Skype name</span>
        </li>
    
        <li>
            <img src="pictures/contact/gadu-gadu.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
            <span>Gadu-Gadu number</span>
        </li>
    
        <li>
            <img src="pictures/contact/email.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
            <span>Email address</span>
        </li>
    
    </div>
  
</body>
```

Unfortunately, these 2 variants are wrong!

Variant number 1:

```css
.box3 > li img
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Variant number 2:

```css
.box3 > li img
{
    padding: 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

padding -> **15px** (as the upper space), **40px** (as the left space) and **0px** (as the bottom space)

How to make 15px of free space under the picture?

I will be very grateful for effective help.

Comment: why are they wrong? Both variants work as expected

Comment: to follow up with first comment https://jsfiddle.net/choezvwk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add margin bottom to LI

```css
body
{
 left: 8%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #6699cc;
}

.box3
{
 background-color: #191919;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 15px 40px 0px;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #DDDDDD;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 12px;
 width: 400px;
}

.box3 > li
{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.box3 > li span
{
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box3">
  
  <li>
   <img src="pictures/contact/skype.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
   <span>Skype name</span>
  </li>
    
  <li>
   <img src="pictures/contact/gadu-gadu.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
   <span>Gadu-Gadu number</span>
  </li>
    
  <li>
   <img src="pictures/contact/email.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
   <span>Email address</span>
  </li>
    
 </div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to post an another question

Comment: Let me have a look... As soon as I will get some free time , will try to help u

Comment: you want a slideshow like this, or specifically this plugin?

Comment: http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/demos/one.html , Check this

Comment: you are using chrome to run this on your local?

Comment: Check if are getting this warning or error in console "Cross-Origin Request Blocked".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never ever put position: absolute on your body element because that will make the element loose its box dimensions. Your body element is actually 0x0 px.

To address your issue, just remove the 0px in the padding, as I did in the code below.

[edit] OK, you wanted all images to have space beneath them, not just the single picture, which was asked in the OP. I added additional code below:

```css
body
{
 left: 8%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #6699cc;
}

.box3
{
 background-color: #191919;
 position: absolute;
 /* padding: 15px 40px 0px; */
 padding: 15px 40px;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #DDDDDD;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 12px;
 width: 400px;
}

.box3 > li
{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.box3 > li span
{
 margin: 5px;
}

/* Added. select li that is followed by an li. */
.box3 > li ~ li {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="box3">
  
  <li>
   <img src="pictures/contact/skype.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
   <span>Skype name</span>
  </li>
    
  <li>
   <img src="pictures/contact/gadu-gadu.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
   <span>Gadu-Gadu number</span>
  </li>
    
  <li>
   <img src="pictures/contact/email.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
   <span>Email address</span>
  </li>
    
 </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Updated my post accordingly to the new information.